# Activiti : End event fired but table act_hi_actinst in database not updated

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I have a bpmn process with one ending accessible by two ways. Theses two ways finish with approximately the same Automatic Task. In one case everything is fine, but not in the second way.

In this second way the end event is correctly fired (I looked in the table `act_hi_actinst` with my **proc_inst_id_** variable) but the column **end_act_id_** is absolutely not updated.. Same for **end_time_** and **duration_**.

I really need this variable to be updated for checking which process is over or not. I don't know if it's important but i have some multi-instance task in my process (canceled by passing through certain tasks).

Thanks for your help!

[end Event in my activiti table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTq0Q.jpg)

Comment: You say "approximately the same Automatic Task". Likely the process is failing and as such never reaching the end event. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: I checked the activiti's table `act_hi_inst` with my process id, and i see in the column `act_type_` my automatic task and just after the "endEvent". 
So i suppose my process is correctly reaching that end event.
I added an image of my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was my multi-instance tasks in my project that fooled me. I put boundary signals on my multi-instance tasks to cancel them when complete certain tasks. I linked thoses boundary signals to my last inclusive gateway, but it was a mistake. Some instances of my multi-instances tasks did not finish properly.

I just linked my boundary signals to the end of the workflow, and it's working well now.